# Indexed query is still very slow in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a simple query like this:

```
 ({ public: false, publicate: 1, timeline: 1, timeline_visibility: true }).sort({ date: -1})
```

I have a specific index for that query and it's being used, but the query is very slow. Here is the output of explain():

```
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor public_1_publicate_1_timeline_1_timeline_visibility_1_date_-1",
"nscanned" : 141461,
"nscannedObjects" : 141461,
"n" : 141461,
"millis" : 535,
"nYields" : 141,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"isMultiKey" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
```

I've tried this with MongoDB 2.0.2, 2.0.9 and 2.4 (all on Linux) – same result. How can I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: That is not the full output of explain however one note, `n` (the number of documents to return) is 141,461. That is a lot of returned documents, in fact, so many MongoDB is yielding to other operations 141 times during the queries run. MongoDB will yield when data is not in RAM, this means that you are having to page in a lot of this data. Why do you need to so many documents to be returned? Can you not limit your set further?

Comment: As @Sammaye mentions the problem is that too many objects match your query. ALthough I don't know what you're trying to do I am guessing the selectivity of your query criteria is very low. You can use limit() to improve the query response speed itself if you cannot reduce the number of documents matching your query.

Comment: Thank you both! Yes, using limit() improves the query significantly. The reason I'm using the query without limit is to get the count of all documents so I can generate pagination.

Comment: Hmm you might have a problem there then. You might wanna look into range based pagination, but your query might be able to be improved. I would look into improving the query seeing if you get narrower results. If not then I would look into range based pagination here